# Separate out Json values with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a Json result that comes  back like this:

```
{ "order_urls": [ "/orders/withoutShipmentDetail/bed2e4cff9f88e041e0d2e4c2", "/orders/withoutShipmentDetail/c924895bc1e4b8640a07216" ] }
```

How do I step into that with PHP to store both order urls in MySQL as separate rows?

Comment: I think you need some code for this. So start with writing some.

Comment: `json_decode()`, then treat it like any other array.

Comment: use `json_decode()` to make it an php array than use a loop to insert it

Comment: Thank you, can I see a code example of the foreach loop to separate that comma separated array?  Right now I have:
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$obj = json_decode($result);
$orderurls = $obj->order_urls; 
print_r($orderurls);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$json       = '{ "order_urls": [ "/orders/withoutShipmentDetail/bed2e4cff9f88e041e0d2e4c2", "/orders/withoutShipmentDetail/c924895bc1e4b8640a07216" ] }';
$decoded    = json_decode($json, true);


foreach($decoded['order_urls'] as $link) {

    //Insert $link into database

}
?>
```